# Sorting an array with similar values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays that contains a date string.

I'd like to sort these arrays by this date.

What seems to be the monkeywrench in this is that some of the arrays share the same value for the date field as well as similar values for tid and/or thing and/or other_thing.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [tid] => 44
            [date] => 1442905200
            [thing] => 2J5265B
            [other_thing] => Scoop
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [tid] => 47
            [date] => 1442905200
            [thing] => 2J5265B
            [other_thing] => Scoop
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [tid] => 48
            [date] => 1430031600
            [thing] => 2E5116A
            [other_thing] => shower
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [tid] => 46
            [date] => 1430031600
            [thing] => 2E5116A
            [other_thing] => shower
        )
    [4] => Array (
            [tid] => 80
            [date] => 1464246000
            [thing] => 7J6147A
            [other_thing] => shower
        )
    [5] => Array (
            [tid] => 47
            [date] => 1442905200
            [thing] => 2J5265B
            [other_thing] => TTT
        )
    [6] => Array (
            [tid] => 44
            [date] => 1442905200
            [thing] => 2J5265B
            [other_thing] => TTT
        )
    [7] => Array (
            [tid] => 46
            [date] => 1504594800
            [thing] => 2J7248A
            [other_thing] => shower
        )
    [8] => Array (
            [tid] => 45
            [date] => 1513238400
            [thing] => 2J7348C
            [other_thing] => TTT
        )
)
```

That's what I'd like to do.

I'd like to sort this array.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `usort()` ([Docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)). This function allows you to specify a comparator to have a user-defined sorting algorithm.

The resulting code might look like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $b['date'] - $a['date'];
}

usort($your_array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

One fast forward solution would be to use the `date` as a key of the array while the array is being build and then you can simply sort keys using [PHP ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

To avoid keys duplicity check if the key is set to handle such situations.

```
// building the data array from database or so
$array = array(); // the array to be sorted
$duplicity = array(); // track the duplicity date records
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $counter = 0;
  @$duplicity[$value['date']]++; // suppressing notices 
  $array[$value['date'].'_'.$duplicity[$value['date']]] = $value;
}
ksort($array);  // sort array by keys
print_r($array);  // just check the sorted array
```

Demo: https://eval.in/978160

More sorting functions [Sorting arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)